# Yii add variable into breadcrumb widget

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I got a quick question, i am trying to get an variable into my breadcrumbs widget, but sadly this isn't working. Am i doing something wrong? I got my code like this:

```
<?php
$this->breadcrumbs = array(
    'item#1'=>array('/controller/action'),
    'item#2'=>array('/controller/action'),
    'item#3'=>array('/controller/action'),
    '{$var->id}'
);
?>
```

Kind regards,

Augus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a simple array, so :

```
<?php
$this->breadcrumbs = array(
  'item#1'=>array('/controller/action'),
  'item#2'=>array('/controller/action'),
  'item#3'=>array('/controller/action'),
  $var->id
);
?>
```

Comment: Ow my, that i didn't think of that. This is the right solution thanks alot!